# Regex pattern for checking if a string starts with a certain substring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

What's the regular expression to check if a string starts with "mailto" or "ftp" or "joe" or...

Now I am using C# and code like this in a big if with many ors:

```
String.StartsWith("mailto:")
String.StartsWith("ftp")
```

It looks like a regex would be better for this. Or is there a C# way I am missing here?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could use:

```
^(mailto|ftp|joe)
```

But to be honest, `StartsWith` is perfectly fine to here. You could rewrite it as follows:

```
string[] prefixes = { "http", "mailto", "joe" };
string s = "joe:bloggs";
bool result = prefixes.Any(prefix => s.StartsWith(prefix));
```

You could also look at the [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class if you are parsing URIs.

Comment: I know this is an old post...but it would be interesting to know the performance statistics for both of these...which is faster?

Answer (score 28):

The following will match on any string that starts with `mailto`, `ftp` or `http`:

```
 RegEx reg = new RegEx("^(mailto|ftp|http)");
```

To break it down:

- `^` matches start of line
- `(mailto|ftp|http)` matches any of the items separated by a `|`

I would find `StartsWith` to be more readable in this case.

Answer (score 12):

The StartsWith method will be faster, as there is no overhead of interpreting a regular expression, but here is how you do it:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, "^(mailto|ftp|joe):")) ...
```

The `^` mathes the start of the string. You can put any protocols between the parentheses separated by `|` characters.

#### edit:

Another approach that is much faster, is to get the start of the string and use in a switch. The switch sets up a hash table with the strings, so it's faster than comparing all the strings:

```
int index = theString.IndexOf(':');
if (index != -1) {
  switch (theString.Substring(0, index)) {
    case "mailto":
    case "ftp":
    case "joe":
      // do something
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: -1, The more strings you add, the more likely the regex is going to be faster I think, since the regex engine will be able to find a match using a single pass of the source string (or less than a pass, if there is no match).  Anyways, I don't think speed is going to be an issue with either method.

Comment: @tster: You are forgetting the short circuit of a condition. If there is a match the `StartsWith` solution by average only have to check half of the strings before it finds the match, or less if they are arranged according to rate of occurance.

Answer (score 4):

For the extension method fans:

```
public static bool RegexStartsWith(this string str, params string[] patterns)
{
    return patterns.Any(pattern => 
       Regex.Match(str, "^("+pattern+")").Success);
}
```

Usage

```
var answer = str.RegexStartsWith("mailto","ftp","joe");
//or
var answer2 = str.RegexStartsWith("mailto|ftp|joe");
//or
bool startsWithWhiteSpace = "  does this start with space or tab?".RegexStartsWith(@"\s");
```

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend using the String.StartsWith method over the Regex.IsMatch if you only plan to check the beginning of a string.

- Firstly, the regular expression in C#
  is a language in a language with does
  not help understanding and code
  maintenance. Regular expression is a
  kind of [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).
- Secondly, many developers does not
  understand regular expressions: it is
  something which is not understandable
  for many humans.
- Thirdly, the StartsWith method brings
  you features to enable culture
  dependant comparison which regular
  expressions are not aware of.

In your case you should use regular expressions only if you plan implementing more complex string comparison in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the substring before ':' using array slices and method String::IndexOf which returns -1 if search substring does not exist. Then you can compare gotten result with constant and logical patterns (C# 9.0+) to check that strings really start with these defined.

```
string s = "ftp:custom";
int index = s.IndexOf(':');
bool result = index > 0 && s[..index] is "mailto" or "ftp" or "joe";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation rather than posting code only.