# Html source and 403 - forbidden

Tags: vb.net

I can see the site [Library Gubkin University](http://elib.gubkin.ru) http://elib.gubkin.ru and its source code with Chrome, Firefox, Webkit test,etc, but when using the code in VB, it appears error 403 forbidden
Why and what can I do to be able to view the source code using VB?

I use the same code that I found on this site

*Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("SomeWebPage")*

from [How to get the source code of a html page using VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818116/how-to-get-the-source-code-of-a-html-page-using-vb-net)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its working fine for me : http://prntscr.com/6s8a0z

Comment: I checked your code, it downloads source code with no error!

Comment: oh, I'm sorry if it still works fine, it just might be blocking network in our dorm.