# Sending current page content as email in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have created an aspx application form with a send button. I need to email the current form contents to a user when I click send button. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at getting the page as an HTML string [How to get the source code of a html page using VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818116/how-to-get-the-source-code-of-a-html-page-using-vb-net)

Then look at adding HTML to an email client. [How to send email in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326738/how-to-send-email-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: Adding a few links does not actually add value to the answer as link's can become dead and not accessible. Could you please update your answer to include the main parts of the links and how they address the OP's issue? If not this could have been a comment or deleted altogether...

Comment: @zaggler due to the fact that OP hasn't shown any research or effort I thought my answer would be applicable. But you are right, I shouldn't of done that, was a **** thing to do.