# VB.net Searching for a string HTML And Substring

Tags: html, vb.net, text, find, substring

How can I find `Color Of The Day:` in a html document from the web?
And then find the text AFTER it like this:

`Color Of The Day: Blue`

The HTML ( Cropped Line ) looks like this:

`<li><strong>Color Of The Day: Blue</strong></li>`

The web's source has a lot of lines up and down.

I'm looking for a way to put `Blue` in a `MsgBox(color)`

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818116/how-to-get-the-source-code-of-a-html-page-using-vb-net

Comment: in combination with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516811/how-do-you-parse-an-html-in-vb-net

Comment: Please try searching by Google or StackOverflow before asking here!

Comment: Please include the failed examples you've tried so far, along with any error messages and error codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First read in the whole string into a variable as normal.  Then use the Replace function to get rid of the part you don't want.

Example:

Let's say you read in and saved the string

"Color Of The Day: Blue" to a variable called withParts

```
Dim withoutParts As String = Replace(withParts, "Color Of The Day: ", "")
```

This will replace the phrase "Color Of The Day: " with nothing, essentially giving you a new string" "Blue" in your new variable withoutParts