# Regular expression for matching start of string with

Tags: c#, regex, vbscript

I need help to built regular expression for

string which does **not** start with pcm_ or PCM_

any guess!!!

Comment: does it allow pCM or PCm or PcM etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex solution would be

```
^(?i)(?!pcm_)
```

`(?i)` is the inline version of `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

`^` matches the start of the string

`(?!pcm_)` is a negative lookahead assertion, that is true if the string does not start with "pcm_" or "PCM_" (but also "PcM_, ...)

Comment: that great hint thanks. i have used this as it is for vbscript ^(?![pP][cC][mM]_)

Answer (score 5):

No need to use regular expression. Use [String.startsWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) method.

```
if (!str.StartsWith("pcm_",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (String.startsWith("pcm_") || String.startsWith("PCM_"))
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

see similar link

[Regex pattern for checking if a string starts with a certain substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750749/regex-pattern-for-checking-if-a-string-starts-with-a-certain-substring)

Comment: This would allow "!pcm_" and "!PCM_" at the start of the string.

Comment: Your modification hasn't improved the expression. "!" is in a regex just the character "!" and not a NOT operater, there is also no AND operator in regex.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, you don't need to use regular expressions for this, but if you wanted to you could use one with negative lookahead like so: `^(?!pcm_|PCM_).*$`

Answer (score 0):

No need for a Regex here, simply use String.StartsWith http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx