# C# How to check if a string contains a specifc combination of chars

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a List, named `values` which contains values similar to the following string values:
`GKgpuzjBUh
IS1bbf2ffd806f6d
IS102a8a395ced93
Dark Von Diakonov
IS148159f7c24f78`

I need to check if the specific a string in the starts with `IS1`

Comment: This `/^IS1/` ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex pattern for checking if a string starts with a certain substring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750749/regex-pattern-for-checking-if-a-string-starts-with-a-certain-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need regex. Use `str.StartsWith("IS1")`.

Comment: is that simple? Really? I feel like a complete idiot

Answer (score 1):

Not clear from the question, so here are a few options.

## You want to find out if ANY string in the list starts with IS1

`var found = values.Any(item => item.StartsWith("IS1"));`

## You want to find all the strings in the list which start with IS1

`var matches = values.Where(item => item.StartsWith("IS1"));`